# Unused Import Error when drawing a Line chart using JFree in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I need to draw a line chart using the database values in *Netbeans*. Currently, I get an unused import error:

```
unused import java.sql.*
```

I don't know why, butif  I remove the import statement I get the following errors, and my graph isn't generated.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008) at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1008)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    at org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset.executeQuery(JDBCCategoryDataset.java:276)
    at org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset.executeQuery(JDBCCategoryDataset.java:191)
    at newchart4.NewChart4.main(NewChart4.java:18)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```

**This is my code:**

```java
import java.sql.*;
import org.jfree.ui.*;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.jdbc.JDBCCategoryDataset;

public class NewChart4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String query = "SELECT * from session_details_table";
        JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kumararaja",
            "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
            "root",
            "test123"
        );
        dataset.executeQuery(query);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "u_id", "s_id", "cpm",
            dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false
        );

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));

        ApplicationFrame f = new ApplicationFrame("Chart");
        f.setContentPane(chartPanel);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So put it back. Ignore the IDE if it gets in the way. You're the boss. It's noot an error anyway, it's a warning.

Comment: If i compile graph is not getting generated..